# Are there any other ways to urinate?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunnah

I'm a new muslim, I've reverted from Hinduism and as a new muslim I'm finding it quick difficult to urinate in a permissible way, I've been trying to sit down and then urinate but due to my pants or maybe because I don't know the proper way to sit for urination I can't do it properly and when I try most of the time some drops of urine falls on my pants, so is there any proper way of siting or just another way of urinate that permissible